# How to update installed hotspot 2.0 profile or how to renew certificates in hotspot profile?

Tags: wireless-networking, certificate, hotspot

I have some device with installed hotspot 2.0/passpoint profile with eap-tls or eap-ttls authentication. The certificates used to authenticate server or client have some lifetime and eventually will expire. I want to know what are the ways to update/renew hotspot 2.0 profiles installed on client device.

Client device are not in AD or not connected to MDM server so this ways are not the option. Also devices are not of the same type and they can be iOS, Android, Mac OS X or Windows devices.